# Foreign key assigned to NULL in JPA one-to-many relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, one-to-many

I have the following pair of entity classes:

```java
@Entity(name="metadata")
public class Metadata {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    // Note: Hibernate CascadeType.ALL is also being used elsewhere in this class, hence
    //       the fully qualified class name used below
    @OneToMany(cascade = javax.persistence.CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "metadata")
    private List<Attachment> attachments;

    // getters and setters
}

@Entity(name="attachment")
public class Attachment {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "metadata_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Metadata metadata;

    // getters and setters
}
```

For completeness, here is how I am building the `Metadata` object:

```java
Metadata metadata = modelMapper.map(req, Metadata.class);
List<Attachment> attachments = new ArrayList<>();
// the files come as a parameter to a Spring controller endpoint (FYI)
for (MultipartFile file : files) {
    Attachment attachment = new Attachment();
    attachment.setContents(file.getBytes());
    attachment.setFilename(file.getOriginalFilename());
    attachments.add(attachment);
}
metadata.setAttachments(attachments);
metadata.setDraft(isDraft);

myJPARepository.save(metadata);
```

What I observe when creating a `Metadata` entity and then calling `save()` from my JPA repository is that all data does get correctly written to my database (Postgres).  However, the join column `metadata_id` is always `NULL`.  At first, I thought this might have been caused due to the `referencedColumnName` attribute not being set (whose default is `""`).  However, adding this in as you see above did remedy the problem.

Does anyone know why the join column `metadata_id` is always appearing as `NULL` in the database table?

Comment: `metadata_id` field is in attachment table/entity right?

Comment: @code_mechanic Yes, for certain the column is there in the `attachment` table (and I never ran any DML to create it...so it must have been created by the JPA framework).  But the value is always `NULL`, for all records, no matter what I try.

Comment: So are you saving the metadata entity or attachment entity using save? and are you setting metadata object into attachment because metadata appears to be parent here?

Comment: I have edited my question with the information you requested.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen How `ScarfonAttachment` and `Attachment` are related between each other?

Comment: @SternK Apologies...I had attempted to mask all my variable names and apparently missed one.  Thanks for catching this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to synch both of your object, as of now you are creating metadata object and adding attachment to it and you have cascade so that will save both entities into their respective table.

But, since you have bidirectional relationship, you are only synching one side of relation ship here only, you need to set the same metadata object to each attachment object as well, then hibernate will be able to link the foreign key.

Instead of setter I would suggest use a add function on metadata object something like this

```
public void addAttachment(Attachment attachment) {
      attachments.add(attachment);
      attachment.setMetadata(this);
}
```

This way both the object would be in synch, use that inside in your for loop, you may have to initialise your collection inside metadata object before doing that or you can first check in above `add` function that if `attachments` list is null then create one and then add.

Comment: I get it (I think).  So you're saying that `private Metadata metadata` is never set, therefore the attachment entities don't "know" about their parent.  Let me try this.

Comment: Yes, this should work, unless I missed something else there.

Comment: Your solution is working +1.  Strange that none of the myriad examples I found online (including some SO answers penned by high rep users) seemed to mention what your answer contains.  Just a quick follow-up: if I could live with a unidirectional one to many, could that also be a way out of my current problem?

Comment: Unidirectional means that relation is defined from one entity only?

Comment: Yes, that is what I had in mind.  If you don't know or don't want to start a conversation here, it is no issue, thanks for helping me get running in any case.

Comment: I recommend everyone to checkout [Vlad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1025118/vlad-mihalcea) blogs, he has shared both pros and cons of every mapping technique

Comment: You can pull off the unidirectional with `id` field I think, but then you would have to save the parent first so that auto increment Id is generated and then you can set into child table as `id` not entity.

Comment: Or, you can remove the mapping altogether from the child (attachment) table, then it should work fine but then you cannot access the parent from child. But beware of this, this would create a mapping table on its own so that can link two tables.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen It's mentioned in the hibernate [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-one-to-many-bidirectional): *Whenever a bidirectional association is formed, the application developer must make sure both sides are in-sync at all times.*

Comment: Yes, unidirectional mapping has pitfalls and one must be aware of them